# WCF deserialization returning 0 list elements

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, deserialization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm having some problems with deserializing an object.

I have following classes:

***Metadatastore:***

```
[DataContract]
public class MetadataStore : IEnumerable<ItemMetadata>
{
    private List<ItemMetadata> data = new List<ItemMetadata>();
    private string folderPath = null;

    [DataMember]        
    public string FilePath
    {
      // getter and setter
    }

    [DataMember]        
    public List<ItemMetadata> Data
    {
      // getter and setter
    }

}
```

***ItemMetadata:***

```
[Serializable()]
public class ItemMetadata
{
 // syncid, syncversion, uristring etc..
}
```

### The problem:

I'm transferring a Metadatastore object from my server(which has a wcf service running) to my client by using an output parameter. So serialization/deserialization of this output param is automatically done by wcf I suppose.
This is what happens:

the client calls the service:

```
service.GetChangeBatch(out metadatastore_object, otherValue);
```

the server responds correctly (metadatastore_object is filled and serialized successfully -> no errors)

the object I receive on client side though is not correct: the FilePath is filled correctly, but the List Data object contains zero elements! I checked also on the server and the data list contained 2 elements. Another strange thing to note is that it isn't either null, it's just a newly created empty list. 
Does somebody has some experience with this, I can provide more code if needed.
Thanks in advance. Greets Daan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CollectionDataContract` instead of `DataContract`.

Here the msdn's explanation about `CollectionDataContract`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx

Comment: That did it! I also had to decorate the ItemMetadata class as a DataContract (like RoccoC5 said)and give them the same namespace on client and server side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be this line:

```
 private List<ItemMetadata> data = new List<ItemMetadata>();
```

That is emptying your list.

Also I would have marked ItemMetadata with DataContract and all properties with DataMember.

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemMetadata` class should also be decorated as a `DataContract` so that the client has knowledge of the type and how to deserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable detailed message logging on wcf service to see what SOAP xml is coming back from the server.

You can then figure out if client is not deserialising xml to object correctly or server is not serialising object to xml correctly.

HTH